# Radio Frequency Switch design problem

Tags: rf, switches, diodes

I am designing a SPDT RF switch that operate within UWB frequency range of 3.1 GHz to 10.6 GHz, the switching element i used is NXP PIN diode model BAP64_02, however I encounter a problem which the diode having bad insertion loss at 10 GHz and I doubting is it the self-resonant problem happen in the diode, if yes, do I have any solution to counter this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The PIN diode is not spec'd past 6GHz.

The self-inductance is 0.6nH; Zl at 10GHz is +j36 ohms.

I imagine you have some DC_blocking caps (100pF each), one on each side of the PIN diode. Also some PCB traces. At 1nH each (cap, trace, trace, cap), or 4nH total, that inductance (if pure inductance) is +j252 ohms.

Is this embedded inside a 50_ohm system? Wavelength of 10GHz is 3.3cm. Are your traces 0.1" wide above 1/16" FR4 above GND? That is 50_ohm with 1/16th" dielectric. Are the capacitors 0.1" wide, so they look (close to) 50_ohms also?

How do you get the current in (50mA, at least)? are those connections acting as tuning-stubs?

If the PIN is self-resonant at 10GHz, run it in a Network Analyzer, and use Smith Chart to define tuning stubs to detune the 10GHz problem.

Comment: yes.. the switches will be embedded in a 50ohm system. the board will be used is roger 4350B

Comment: can i use the ADS software to simulate the diode frequency response on smith chart then define the tuning stubs? but the smith chart i get is somehow very different with what learn from pozar's book

Comment: Does a small inductance (2nH) push the SmithChart away from the center (50 ohm) and out to the edge? Be careful; you need a broad-band solution over 5GHz to 10GHz. Avoid sharp resonances.

Comment: i have try with inductance in series and also shunt.. but nth much affect on the center of smith chart.. the 10GHz still crossing at the center point